# Cannot create Soup from Guardian article fetched with urllib2.urlopen

Tags: beautifulsoup, urllib2, python-2.7, urlopen

I somehow cannot create a soup from a Guardian article I am fetching with urllib2.urlopen() when the same code works with another url.
Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/2012/mar/29/jessica-ennis-london-2012'
myfile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = myfile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
```

which triggers the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/myhome/workspace/guardiangrep/testing.py", line 13, in 
>       soup = BeautifulSoup(data)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.0.2-py2.7.egg/bs4/**init**.py",
>   line 168, in **init**
>       self._feed()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.0.2-py2.7.egg/bs4/**init**.py",
>   line 181, in _feed
>       self.builder.feed(self.markup)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.0.2-py2.7.egg/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py",
>   line 133, in feed
>       parser.feed(markup)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 108, in feed
>       self.goahead(0)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 148, in goahead
>       k = self.parse_starttag(i)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 229, in parse_starttag
>       endpos = self.check_for_whole_start_tag(i)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 304, in
>   check_for_whole_start_tag
>       self.error("malformed start tag")   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 115, in error
>       raise HTMLParseError(message, self.getpos()) HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 3025, column
>   16

I understand headers might be useful info in this case. If I add

```
headers = myfile.info()
print headers
```

I get

> Server: Apache X-GU-jas: 05-1559 Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
>   X-GU-gen-jas: 05 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 P3P: CP="CAO
>   CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa PSAa PSDa IVAa IVDa CONa TELa OUR IND ONLi UNI
>   PURi NAV STA PRE LOC" Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2012 09:10:54 GMT
>   X-GU-PageRenderer: DefaultPageRenderer Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=70
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked X-GU-tm: 01 Content-Language: en-US
>   Connection: close X-GU-httpd: 05

### Any help is most appreciated.

edit:
Reverting to BeautifulSoup 3 seems to correct the issue. Puzzling!

Answer (score 1):

I received the following answer through other channels from Leonard Richardson. It solved my problem

You're using Python's built-in parser class, HTMLParser, which is not as lenient as the built-in SGMLParser used by Beautiful Soup 3.

The built-in HTMLParser becomes more lenient starting in Python 2.7.3 and Python 3.2.2, but the simplest solution is to install an external parsing library. Either lxml or html5lib should be able to parse this document.

This is explained here:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser